# Visual Studio 2022 not showing parameter XML docs tooltips on mouse over

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2022, xml-comments

As pictured, the "param" part of the summary is not showing on mouse over panel.
Should I expect them to be there or is the "param" functionality not working as I think it should?
The other tags work (like "remarks" etc.), so I assume I'm just not looking in the right place to see where "param" shows up. I thought they would show on the mouse over panel.
[image]

Did a bunch of searching online, but I couldn't find anything related specifically to this issue.

EDIT:
In response to below:
Mouse was over the function name. When I mouse over the parameter, the description shows. This isn't the functionality I was looking for though, as if I can mouse over the parameter I can instead just read the actual comment.

Below, someone pointed out that maybe it's because I was mousing over the function declaration instead of a call to the function. This was something I thought of before posting, but I will post what I see when I mouse over a call to a function with the summary and parameter tags, and a picture of when I am attempting to input parameters into said call.

Adding parameters:

[image: Adding parameters to function with summary tag]

Mousing over function call:

[image]

Interestingly, the "remarks" tags work, but only when mousing over the name of the method (either when invoking or mousing over the declaration), but still nothing shows up when the panel appears when inputting parameters into a call/invocation of the method.

[image]

Comment: Where is your mouse? Are you hovering over `_vA`? https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrcVg.png

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a "typo" with your mouse. You have your mouse in the wrong position - hover over the parameter not the method name.

Comment: I don't think VS will by default show params in the method overview, for that I suspect you will need ReSharper.   VS will show parameter help as you begin typing the method arguments.  i.e. when you are _invoking_ the method.

Comment: I have edited my question with more information for clarity.
@MickyD No joy on that. I had tested it before asking but didn't clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellisense doesn't treat the param tag the way you want it to.

These are the times where you can see the info specified in the param tags:

1. When hovering directly over the parameters - not so helpful as the OP mentioned as you have visibility of the param tags anyway
2. When providing values for the parameters when calling the method - this is the more helpful instance

Note: The OP mentioned that remarks shows when hovering over the method name. This is because remarks relate the whole method and are important to see along with the summary. Parameter info can become cumbersome for methods with many parameters so they are probably not shown when hovering over the method to make things cleaner.

I'm including a link that describes intellisense behaviour in relation to the param tags: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2022#:~:text=Completion%20Mode.-,Parameter%20Info,-Parameter%20Info%20gives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2022#:%7E:text=Completion%20Mode.-,Parameter%20Info,-Parameter%20Info%20gives)

Comment: Yeah, that works, but it's kind of pointless since if I can mouse over the parameter I can just read the actual comment block itself. I was looking for the popup panel to include all of the relevant information. I have updated my original question for clarity and to show what my issue actually looks like.

Apologies for not being clear from the outset.

Comment: Yes, @Pixnek gave an answer showing another instance where the param can be viewed. But I don't  think VS works how you want it to by default. I think it would be quite cumbersome to show the param info with the summary as some methods can have many parameters.

Comment: Interesting. I will have to look further into how to get the behavior that I desire in VS2022. Thanks for your time!

Comment: No problem at all

Answer (score -2):

The description of the parameters is visible when calling this method

[image]

[image]

Comment: _[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_.  Consider editing your answer to contain a summary of the article pointed to by the link.